# Bootstrap modals in single page and Google reCaptcha on both modals

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

My PHP page contain two links.

```
Link 1 -> modal1
Link 2 -> modal2
```

Both modals contain google reCaptcha v2. reCaptcha verification in modal1 is fine. But I am not getting grecaptcha. Response length in modal2. It is always 0. Hence no verification.

Also, After successful verification in modal1. I need not to verify in modal2. Means, recaptcha verification of modal1 is automatically implemented on modal2.
Strange, The error message in modal1 if verification failed, is picking css styles from modal2.

Comment: What is your question? How did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: Problem solved. Both of the modals are pop up window of same page. So recaptcha response was coming back to the code of modal that was placed at first.